# Changing validation based on type using FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce, fluentvalidation

I have a simply model like so:

```
[Validator(typeof(EntryModelValidator))]
public class EntryModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
  public virtual string ProductActionValue { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using FluentValidation to validate the saving of the model. The issue is that when the user saves the values on the form, in certain situations ProductActionValue needs to be saved as an int (it will of course always be saved as a string, but it needs to be parseable as an int).

I have the following Validation rule which ensures the value is not empty:

```
 RuleFor(x => x.ProductCriteriaValue)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Common.FieldRequired"));
```

I tried adding the following rule to validate as an int:

```
 RuleFor(x => Int32.Parse(x.ProductCriteriaValue))
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1)
            .When(x => (ProductCriteriaTypes)x.ProductCriteriaTypeId == ProductCriteriaTypes.ProductCreatedGreaterThanXDays || (ProductCriteriaTypes)x.ProductCriteriaTypeId == ProductCriteriaTypes.ProductCreatedLessThanXDays)
            .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Common.FieldRequired"));
```

But this just throws FluentValidation runtime errors. Is there anyway to acheive this?

Thanks in advance
Al

UPDATED TO REFLECT AHMAD'S SOLUTION:

```
   {
        RuleFor(x => x.ProductCriteriaValue)
            .Must(BeANumber)
            .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Common.FieldRequired"));
   }

    private bool BeANumber(string value)
    {
        int result;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value, out result))
        {
            return result >= 1;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't used this framework, but couldn't you leave it as a string and validate it with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Predicate Validator (aka Must)](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Validators&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Predicate):

```
RuleFor(x => x.ProductCriteriaValue)
    .Must(x => Int32.Parse(x.ProductCriteriaValue) >= 1)
    .When(x => (ProductCriteriaTypes)x.ProductCriteriaTypeId == ProductCriteriaTypes.ProductCreatedGreaterThanXDays || (ProductCriteriaTypes)x.ProductCriteriaTypeId == ProductCriteriaTypes.ProductCreatedLessThanXDays)
    .WithMessage(localizationService.GetResource("Common.FieldRequired"));
```

Of course, this assumes that the parse won't fail. Will `ProductCriteriaValue` always be a number and parse fine? If so, this is ok. Otherwise, you might want to check this better by using `Int32.TryParse` and changing the predicate as follows:

```
    .Must(x =>
    {
        int result;
        if (Int32.TryParse(x.ProductCriteriaValue, out result))
        {
            return result >= 1;
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad - great answer, but it doesnt seen to quite work. The form will still submit without validating. I've updated the post to show what I now have and it doesn' work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @higgsy any errors? Or the model just doesn't go through any of your validators? And you've gone through the [ASP.NET MVC integration steps](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc)?

Comment: Hi, yes there are lots of other rules working perfectly. Just not that particular one.....

Comment: @higgsy if your earlier `NonEmpty` rule worked for this, and the new one isn't working, have you checked that the `When` condition is being met? i.e., put a breakpoint on the method that accepts your model when the form is submitted, and check that `ProductCriteriaTypeId` does indeed match the expected criteria specified by the `When` condition used in the FV rule.

Comment: Hi Ahmad - I actually removed the .When condition just to tets, and it still doesnt validate...

Comment: @higgsy that's odd. What about placing a breakpoint in the `BeANumber` method? Does it get hit at all?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13970791/1882637) which uses separate validator classes for the same view model. In addition, note that you can use a base class for the 2 validator classes to contain the common rules to avoid duplication of your validation rules.